# how to extract specific values from array inside array of jsons in js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to display the name of persons whose favorite color is pink from an array of multiple jsons. Which method or logic I should use in javascript or jQuery?

```
var person = [{
"name":"Angel",
"age":23,
"color":[ "pink", "purple", "white" ]
},
{
"name":"Harry",
"age":20,
"color":[ "pink", "yellow" , "red" ]
},
{
"name":"Ella",
"age":21,
"color":[ "green", "gray", "black" ]
}];
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter](filter) or [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map](map) and [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some](some) or [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes](includes)

Comment: actually, I am new and I only tried basic so I don't know how to extract this specific value! I haven't work in multiple json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions

```js
var person = [{
"name":"Angel",
"age":23,
"color":[ "pink", "purple", "white" ]
},
{
"name":"Harry",
"age":20,
"color":[ "pink", "yellow" , "red" ]
},
{
"name":"Ella",
"age":21,
"color":[ "green", "gray", "black" ]
}];

var names = person.filter(x => x.color.includes('pink')).map(x => x.name);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `forEach`

```js
var person = [{
"name":"Angel",
"age":23,
"color":[ "pink", "purple", "white" ]
},
{
"name":"Harry",
"age":20,
"color":[ "pink", "yellow" , "red" ]
},
{
"name":"Ella",
"age":21,
"color":[ "green", "gray", "black" ]
}];
var arr=[];
person.forEach(function(e){
if(e.color.filter(function(k){return k=="pink"}).length>=1)
arr.push( e.name)
})
console.log(arr)
```